# User not showing in the user list in the CP but has profile after social login?

Tags: users, user-profile, plugin-social-login

Something strange going on with the user listings in the CP. Using craft v2.6.2794 and social logins v 1.2.4.

I am using the social logins plugin for craft 2 and just updated it to the latest version. It creates a social login and a user and from the social login listing I can browse to the user profile. However when I try to view the user in the listing page it does not show up even after searching or listing as last created but it is there.
Any ideas. There are over 21k users in the db.

Comment: Update if I try to delete the profile it gives the error:

No element exists with the ID(xxxx)

So looks like the social login isn't creating an element in the db.

Comment: This sounds more like a bug in the code so it might be a better idea to contact the creator of the plugin. Unless you show us your custom code there is nothing we can do.